# Call notifyDataSetChanged on back press

Tags: android, listview, fragment, adapter

I have a grid of images that came from the server so for that I have one Adapter class one `fragment`.
Now on click on the image, I open up another `fragment` with `adapter` with a full screen that is in ViewPager.

Now some are Pro images, if the user clicks on Pro `button` then all image that has pro have removed that tag so I successfully remove pro from full screen `adapter`. Now when the user for back to full page image to grid image list how do I update that list so that all protag is removed from that adapter?

So far I created a method in full-page `adapter`

```
public void dataChanged() {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and call it when the user clicks on back `button`

```
        gridAdapter.dataChanged();
```

but didn't update the list. What I'm missing here

Comment: Which layout container do you use? `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` or `GridView`?

Comment: im using GridLayoutManager

Comment: Then try `notifyItemRemoved()` ,`notifyItemRangeRemoved()` after remove pro image from dataGridList, and notify inserted after add them again.

Comment: I think `notifyDataSetChanged()` works, most likely a bug in adapter, show adapter code.

Comment: @UgAr0FF  If you are writing an adapter it will always be more efficient to use the more
         * specific change events if you can.

Comment: Please your question with code of adding/removing pro images ?

Comment: pro is tag on image so there is no image remove from list, it just remove tag only from images

Comment: @Khaled Lela In this case, notifyDataSetChanged () doesn't work, so the specific change events will not work too

Comment: @UgAr0FF My suggestion is not related to fix QP but it's **roll of thumb** of good design suggested by [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()). then fix this issue need extra info about adapter.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: can you please edit your question and add your code to provide more info about your problem.